# Django Rest allauth Keycloak dj-rest-auth authentication PKCE code verifier not specified

Tags: django, keycloak, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I'm trying to retrieve access and refresh token from django rest framework(simple jwt) through keycloak authentication.
I extended dj-rest_auth.registration.views SocialLoginView for retrieving the token,
but I'm getting an error like

> allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client.OAuth2Error: Error retrieving access token: b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"PKCE code verifier not specified"}'

please forgive me if there is any misunderstanding in my code and please help.

Comment: Which KC version are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.